# how to move file another folder using asp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to move existing file to another folder using asp, but i will send file series "scn_1" only

```
FROM -- > d:\image\scn_1_1.jpg , d:]image\scn_1_2.jpg

TO -->   d:\image2\backup\scn_1_1.jpg, scn_1_2.jpg
```

in asp or vb

this is my sample code

```
    Dim fs
    fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim scanpath = Request.QueryString("spath")
    Dim rkpath = Request.QueryString("rkpath")
    Dim series = Request.QueryString("series")
    fs.MoveFile("D:\Ethiraj\ScanDcocument\scanimage\test.txt", "D:\Ethiraj\ScanDcocument\Rk_Images\test.txt")
    fs = Nothing
```

Comment: `in asp or vb` you do know `asp` is not a language right? ***Show us what you have tried...***

Comment: Please don't make this as a comment rather include it in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Dim fs fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") Dim scanpath = Request.QueryString("virtu_dir") Dim rkpath = Request.QueryString("RK_path") Dim series = Request.QueryString("series") Dim fileToFind = series & "*.jpg" Dim dirs As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(scanpath, fileToFind) Dim dir As String For Each dir In dirs If dir.Contains(series) Then Dim filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dir) fs.CopyFile(dir, rkpath + "\" + filename) fs = Nothing End If Next